# mask data id card number in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some data resembling the following:

> 444444444444444

I want to add a mask to the data so it looks like this:

> 44.444.444.4-444.444

I tried using:

```
$x_data = preg_replace('~.{3}\K(?!$)~', '.', $x_data);
```

Which got me:

> 444.444.444.444.444

How do I modify my preg_replace to give me the exact output I am looking for?

Comment: What is the logic for placing the `-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a capture group approach, and then connect the subcomponents according to the format you are expecting.

```
$x_data = "444444444444444";
echo $x_data . "\n";
$x_data = preg_replace('/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})$/',
                       '$1.$2.$3.$4-$5.$6',
                       $x_data);
echo $x_data;
```

This prints:

```
444444444444444
44.444.444.4-444.444
```